# ¿Cómo configurar un rango correctamente un rango con vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Es una parte de una macros, en la que necesito configurar un Rango para llamarlo después a en Solver. Al momento de correr la Macros me resulta un error '1004  en tiempo de ejecución
Error definido por la aplicación o en el objeto. En la parte de Set...

```
Sub busquedadecantidad()
Dim i As Integer
Dim cant As Range
Dim bin As Range
cantidadabajo = Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row
cantidadarriba = Range("D1").Offset(1, 0).Row

binarioabajo = Range("G1").End(xlDown).Row
binarioarriba = Range("G1").Offset(1, 0).Row

cantidad = Range("D" & cantidadabajo & ":D" & cantidadarriba).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
binario = Range("G" & binarioabajo & ":G" & binarioarriba).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

Set cant = Worksheets("valor del inventario").Range(cantidad)
Set bin = Worksheets("valor del inventario").Range(binario)

End Sub
```

El error que me salta es:

> Se ha producido el error 1004 en tiempo de ejecución: Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto.

Haciendo clic en Depurar me selecciona la línea:

```
Set cant = Worksheets("valor del inventario").Range(cantidad)
```

Comment: `Cantidad` está vacía cuando lo llamas como argumento. VBA está esperando un valor en plan `A1` o `D3:D10` pero tu línea `cantidad = Range("D" & cantidadabajo & ":D" & cantidadarriba).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select` no tiene sentido, porque no hace nada ni guardas nada en `cantidad`. Lo mismo se aplica a `binario`

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo guardar tal rango para después llamarlo? ¿Tengo que declararlo como Rango y usar Set para indicar que es un rango?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te complicas en exceso:

Declaras el rango con Dim cantidad as Range. Declaras también una hoja del libro con Dim hoja as Worksheet.

Luego defines la variable hoja y el rango cantidad con Set. Un ejemplo montando sólo el rango cantidad:

```
Dim cantidad As Range
Dim hoja As Worksheet
cantidadabajo = Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row
cantidadarriba = Range("D1").Offset(1, 0).Row

Set hoja = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("valor del inventario")
Set cantidad = hoja.Range("D" & cantidadabajo & ":D" & cantidadarriba)
```

Tendrás que hacer lo mismo con el rango binario.

Suerte.

Comment: Muchas gracias, parece que fallaba porque no definí a la hoja como una Worksheet. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Al final quedó así

Sub busquedadecantidad()

            Dim cantidad As Range
            Dim hoja As Worksheet
            Set hoja = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("valor del inventario")
            Set cantidad = hoja.Range("G" & cantidadabajo & ":G" & 
            cantidadarriba).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End Sub

Comment: Tu problema es que estabas haciendo un Select en el rango cantidad y ese Select no devuelve valores, tan sólo selecciona el rango. Sin más.